# WebView Shows Nothing When Loading Local Html Javafx

Tags: javafx, webview, fxml

Pretty much in the title. Here is the code that opens WebView

```
protected void showWebContent(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {     
        WebView webView = new WebView();
        webView.getEngine().load(getFilePath());
        System.out.println("FILE PATH FOR WEBVIEW IS: " + getFilePath());
        getStage().setScene(new Scene(webView));
        getStage().setTitle("WebView");
        getStage().show();
    }
```

However it shows just an empty page

[image]

This is what I get when I extract the URL as String

```
FILE PATH FOR WEBVIEW IS: /home/nikki/ArcticNews (copy)/index.html
```

**SOLUTION:**

```
new File(getFilePath()).toURI().toURL().toExternalForm()
```

Comment: The `load` method is expecting a URL, not a file system path.

Comment: That's odd because when I try to load URL it says incompatible types, URI cannot be converted to String. What would be the correct way to pass local html as URL then? EDIT: got it. Added solution